# PHP project links being redirected to the wamp server page

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

*My apologies if this has been posted*

I've created a PHP project and I'm using Wamp I've also got a database set up in phpmyadmin.

I am able to run my website and view my website, but when I click on a link *(my catalog with different categories link to display products)*. The link redirects me to the wamp server page.

Does anyone have a solution to this, any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<a href="/?page=catalogue-item&amp;category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>&amp;id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo Helper::encodeHtml($row['name'], 1); ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" />
</a>
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: doesnt seems like an netbeans issue...

Comment: Could it be a wampserver issue? God I hope its not my php scripting.

Comment: provide that `link code`...

Comment: Probably there is an problem with the link just or there is something inside your script like `header("location:...")` which is doing this.

Comment: Not sure how to add a link code or what that even means.

Comment: <a href="/?page=catalogue-item&amp;category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>&amp;id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo Helper::encodeHtml($row['name'], 1); ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" /></a>

Comment: in which folder it is ? is it in root if so are you handling $_GET variables properly ?

Comment: When I run the website[link](http://localhost/liquoriceland/index.php)  When I click on a link [link](http://localhost/?page=catalogue&category=1) It displays the wampserver page I hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: @Subhanker it is in my pages folder labelled catalogue.php I have a classes folder that stores my methods Catalogue.php this has all my functions inside that.

Comment: Check my answer and please post formatted codes in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
<a href="?page=catalogue-item&amp;category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>&amp;id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo Helper::encodeHtml($row['name'], 1); ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" />
</a>
```

`/` Was was the actual problem which was making the link point to root instead of current page.

Comment: I removed the slash and it still takes me to the wampserver homepage.

Comment: press ctrl+u find the html output of this code and paste it in comments

Comment: `<li><a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=6">Allsorts</a></li><li>a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=5">Combination</a></li>li>a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=2">Fudge</a></li><li>a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=1">Liquorice</a></li><li><a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=7">Liquorice Straps</a></li><li>a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=3">Nougat</a></li><li><a href="/?page=catalogue&amp;category=4">Toffee</a></li>`

Comment: see / is still before?  you need to remove that

Comment: I removed the / from my header.php file\"/? `echo "<li><a href=\"?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']` Also removed it from my catalogue.php file and ran the project clicked on the links and I didn't go to the wampserver page. Wonderful! Thank you so much for your help @Subhanker